# Двойной рендер React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

При рендере компонента запрос делается два раза и из-за этого получаю при пагинации одинаковые карточки Что с этим делать? В чем может быть проблема?

Использую React и Redux

```js
export const fetchCars = createAsyncThunk(
   "cars/fetchAll",
   async (page, {rejectWithValue}) => {
     try {
      const url = new URL('https://6542095af0b8287df1ff5f9e.mockapi.io/Adverts');
      url.searchParams.append('p', page);
      url.searchParams.append('l', 12); 
       const response = await axios.get(url);
       return response.data;
     } catch (e) {
       return rejectWithValue(e.message);
     }
   }
 );
```

```js
const handlePending = state => {
   state.isLoading = true;
 };
 const handleRejected = (state, action) => {
   state.isLoading = false;
   state.error = action.payload;
 };

 const carsSlice = createSlice({
   name: 'cars',
   initialState: {
     items: [],
     isLoading: false,
     error: null,
   },
   reducers: {},
   extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchCars.pending, handlePending)
      .addCase(fetchCars.rejected, handleRejected)
      .addCase(fetchCars.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.error = null;
        state.items = [...state.items, ...action.payload];
      });
  },
   },
 );
```

Comment: Если реакт 18+, то в строгом режиме, в среде разработки, он выполняет установку компонентов дважды(заявлено как фича, а не бага). Попробуйте убрать строгий режим(`<React.StrictMode>`) и проверить. Если двойной рендер останется, значит проблема с кодом и идет двойная отрисовка компонента(тут уже надо смотреть, как и кто может его повторно дергать)

Comment: На жаль, проблема не в StrictMode

Comment: Але і в коді немає повторного виклику